# ScrollViewUI won't load unless it's the initial view controller

Tags: ios, xcode

ScrollViewUI won't load unless it's the initial view controller but I want the login/sign up view controllers to load first. Only after the login/sign up has completed, I want the ScrollViewUI to load.

When the ScrollViewUI isn't the  initial view controller, it returns a nil value as expected. Although, I want to fix this error. Can anybody help?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Be carefull when using words like "crap" or "wtf" in the UI. It's a cause of non-acceptance on the AppStore ;-)

Comment: Here's the code http://i.gyazo.com/79a16fc3615dbab69d45ab2c36384eab.png & http://i.gyazo.com/a037297f4996e1e52b05c81052508892.png

Comment: You should look at UIStoryboard's instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method, I don't see it anywhere in the code, and it's the only way to instantiate the view containing the Scroll View ! https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateInitialViewController

Comment: Basically, as the code for the ScrollViewUI is in the ViewDidLoad() it thinks that the scroll view is going to initialise as soon as the app starts but that's not the case. I tried to put it into a function but then got that sigbrt error which is annoying... :(

Comment: @Dean The view containing the ScrollViewUI has the correct identifier used and it still doesn't work. I can't see what the problem is. Can you ask some of your friends? I'm stuck :[

Comment: Have you set up the reuse identifier for your controller on the Interface Builder? If not, instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier will return nil since it won't be able to find a controller inside your storyboard with a matching identifier.

Comment: @halileohalilei Do you mean the restoration identifier? I've set that to MainViewController which is also the storyboard identifier but no difference!

Comment: I thought I'd try and put the code under where I've gone and done  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and now there's a different error --> http://i.gyazo.com/f59854c7c20262ba0610a380074b7ea5.png

Comment: @JamieMathieson I meant the Storyboard ID. Have you also set your custom classes to your controllers from the InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: @halileohalilei The classes aren't used for anything, I simply used them to create nibs to make interface building really neat and tidy. I learnt that the ViewDidLoad() expects the ScrollViewUI to be the first thing shown on the app and it's not because the initial view controller is the login/sign up view controller and so after a user logs in, I called the ScrollViewUI and this caused libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @Dean  Can I send you the Xcode project over to take a look at please?

Comment: @halileohalilei  Can I send you the Xcode project over to take a look at please?

Comment: Help please http://i.gyazo.com/69be6adad993dd0782db7f2ab12d051b.png